# Change clipping of objects in matplotlib 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I plot a 3D polygon and plot a scatterpoint on the face. However, the alpha of the scatterpoint changes so that it looks like it is under the polygon, rather than on the edge, depending on the orientation. How can I fix so it clips correctly?

```
collection = Poly3DCollection(verts, linewidths=1, edgecolors='black', alpha=0.5)
face_color = "salmon"
collection.set_facecolor(face_color)
ax.add_collection3d(collection)


ax.scatter(-.5,-.5,0,color='black',alpha=1,s=30)
ax.scatter(0,0,1,color='black',alpha=1)
ax.scatter(-1,0,0,color='black',alpha=1)
```

Scatterplot behind polygon:

[image: scatterplot behind polygon]

Scatterplot above polygon:
[image: scatterplot above polygon]

I tried changing the order of plotting, and the alpha values for each plot point. However, it still always looks underneath completely from certain orientations.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't support full 3D.  Matplotlib's 3D faq suggests the Mayavi library if you need more capabilities.

Comment: please add the imports that you are using: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example